# How to get response from subqueries SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, sql-order-by

I have 2 views which are supposed to sort a table and return maximum of a column. I don`t know how to get rid of SortedFilms and BiggestCount views.

```
create view SortedFilms as
select movie_genres.gen_id, movie_genres.mov_id, movie.mov_title, movie.mov_year, movie.mov_rel_country
from movie_genres
full join movie ON movie.mov_id = movie_genres.mov_id
where gen_id = '1007'
group by 
    movie_genres.mov_id,
    movie_genres.gen_id,
    movie.mov_title,
    movie.mov_rel_country,
    movie.mov_year;
```

```
create view BiggestCount as
select mov_year, count(mov_year)
from SortedFilms
group by
    mov_year
having 
    count (mov_year)=(
    select max(occurence_count)
    from (
        select mov_year, count(mov_year) occurence_count
        from SortedFilms
        group by mov_year) subquery);
```

Here should be a single view. I know that I should insert code of those views instead of SortedFilms and BiggestCount, but when it comes to `where` condition, I don`t know how to compare responses of 2 subqueries.

```
select SortedFilms.mov_title, SortedFilms.mov_year, SortedFilms.mov_rel_country
from SortedFilms
full join BiggestCount ON BiggestCount.mov_year = SortedFilms.mov_year
where SortedFilms.mov_year = BiggestCount.mov_year
order by SortedFilms.mov_year;
```

Comment: You've tagged Postgresql and also t-sql; if you actually read the description of the t-sql tag it includes *Do not use this tag for MySQL, PostgreSql, Oracle(Pl/SQL) related queries.* - so what database are you really using? Also your first view is called *sorted*Films but does not do any sorting (which really it shouldn't anyway), and you don't aggregate anything either, so why are you grouping? Please provide a clearer description of what you require.

Comment: I need to get a table which contains films of a year with most film occurrences of a single genre with id '1007'. It`s postgresql.

Comment: Solved by using `where ... in...` and pasting code from BiggestCount and Sorted films.